# How to create a Color Identifier?

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a Script to identify colors that appear on my computer monitor. The idea is that whenever a color appears on the monitor, a click is executed.
My problem is that this needs to be done considering the whole monitor and not just the browser page, so if I minimize the monitor and this color appears on my desktop I want the click to happen.
I wanted to know if JavaScript can do this and what paths I should follow to be able to implement it.

Comment: JavaScript can only monitor what happens on one browser page and not on your monitor

Comment: Why would you want any arbitrary website to be able to silently grab an image of your entire monitor via in-browser JavaScript…? This would be a gaping security issue. It’s possible you can do this in JavaScript albeit *outside* a browser context with the facilities available in a runtime like Node.js, but I can’t say for certain.

Comment: It's just out of curiosity, I had an idea for a small academic project and as I'm more familiar with JavaScript, I thought about using JavaScript.
But I've never seen anything like that with JS.

Comment: No, for security reasons obviously.  However, you may want to research open source projects that do something close.  There is a Chrome extension that can read colours [Chrome Eye Dropper](https://github.com/kepi/chromeEyeDropper) and for reading colours from the entire screen there is a C++ project [Instant Eye Dropper](http://instant-eyedropper.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use this lib https://github.com/seiyria/pixcolor which is based on a `edge-js` fork which let *C#* code to interact with JS. Then once you got the pixel colors you could use https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs to automate system click.